# Memory allocated for Python process

Tags: python, memory, operating-system

By default how much memory is allocated by the operating system for a python process?

Usually operating system allocates memory for each process. So when we execute a python file, a process will initiated and the operating system will allocate memory for this python process. So what is the default memory allocated by operating system for a python process.

I also want to know how the code, data, heap segments work in Python. Is there any good document for understanding Python internals?

Comment: The Python docs have a Memory Management section.

Comment: as a starting point, https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/memory.html

Comment: @WesDoyle Thanks, will look into it